# RaspBerry PI 2B loses ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet, windows-iot

I have a RaspBerry PI 2B running Windows IoT Core connected via an ethernet cable to the internet. Sometimes, and mostly after a reboot/power outage, it isn't able to connect with the internet. Without an internet connection the PI becomes useless to me because I'm not able to ping it, remote-control it (with PowerShell), ...

Now when I extract the SD card, burn a fresh image back on it and insert it into the PI the ethernet connection works again.

Anyone has an idea on what is causing this?

Comment: Have you checked your router? I would guess that is the problem.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a router issue? All other connected devices remain their connectivity, also other RaspBerry PI's.

Comment: I would ask if you could post some log files but I do not know what/where they would be on a widows-iot Pi!  Can you find such things on the SD card - assuming that it hasn't been too badly corrupted when you have to switch the Pi off with *dirty* (or more politely, possibly *inconsistent*) file-systems because you can't get into it to shut it down cleanly?  Obviously you want to do this **before** you overwrite the SD card, *again*! 8-)

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: No never figured out what the problem was ... Sad to hear people are still facing this issue.